# The votes after hitting cap aren't loading properly

Tags: bug, reputation-history

I hit my rep cap at 18:01, but my profile isn't showing the new votes. I can see on my mobile that I have had 5 upvotes since then, but only one is showing on my desktop.

By time:

[image]

By post:

[image]

And the posts listed have more votes on them than show on the list. [this one is one of them.](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14194/can-i-graft-elderberries-sambucus/14205#14205) Sorted by time, you only see three votes on it, and it actually has 4.

Now I've refreshed the page on my mobile, and the last vote is not shown.

Comment: This is by design; the votes are grouped, but new votes are first shown separately (grouped when not giving you reputation), then later grouped with the previous votes.

Comment: @Martijn Why then did the most recent vote disappear from my desktop when I refreshed the page from my mobile?

Comment: Your mobile marks the rep history as 'seen', so the votes are once again grouped.

Comment: On my mobile, They are all listed one above the other, as empty votes. On my desktop, they are doing the same thing, like normal, until I refresh the page *from my mobile*. Then it gets all messed up. Still looks fine from my phone.

Comment: Just got empty vote #6, which is doing the same thing.

Comment: Yes, because the desktop revision history shows votes grouped by post, even in the by time view there is grouping going on. The mobile view shows you individual votes, always.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Only if it is the same post that gets voted. They should stop grouping when another post is voted on.

Comment: But they are not grouping *until you viewed your rep history*. But viewing on mobile counts as a view. If you view *only on the desktop* you'll see the posts are not grouped.

Comment: @Martijn Look at July 16 [here](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/users/419/j-musser?tab=reputation&sort=time&StartDate=2014-09-29%2020:34:02Z&page=3). You can see the empty votes by themselves.

Comment: Yes, because there were no votes for those posts that did give reputation.

Comment: I see this every day on Stack Overflow, the behaviour is entirely deterministic and by design.

Comment: @Martijn Why does the last vote remain on its own, even when the page is refreshed? It has been voted on before that same day.

Comment: The last vote doesn't remain on its own. It just means the group has been sorted to the top now.

Comment: My last vote is still appearing on its own.

Comment: I'll have to wait for a vote on a post I already received points for today (I hit the cap on Stack Overflow some 7 hours or so ago) to see again what happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no bug here. The mobile and desktop views differ in how they display votes, that is all.

On the desktop, *new* votes are shown as distinct from old posts, and votes in each category are grouped per post, per vote type (downvotes separate from upvotes separate from accepts, etc.). If you have not looked at your reputation tab in a while, new votes for post A are shown grouped separate from new votes for post B, both separate from votes for those same posts you have already 'seen'.

In the *by time* view the order in which the grouped votes appear is by most-recent vote timestamp; if you received votes for a post at midnight and at noon, the noon vote determines the sort order.

On mobile, all votes are shown in the order they arrived, newest first, and no 'new' highlighting is applied.

However, viewing your votes on mobile resets the 'last viewed' timestamp. As such, viewing your votes on mobile first, then on the desktop, means you won't see those new votes grouped separately anymore.